# How to fix Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

Can someone help me with this error?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-google-signin:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find play-services-auth.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/12.0.1/play-services-auth-12.0.1.jar

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your android/build.gradle with this i.e in your project level gradle with this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"} //<---- this should be added and should be aboce jcenter
        maven {url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"}
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

After that clear your gradle going inside android folder from cmd/terminal
gradlew clean
Then run the react native application